# htaccess to remove PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been searching on the Internet for quite awhile now and I can't seem to find a working htaccess for my website. I am using a news CMS called CuteNews and they have a function that allows for URL rewrites. However, the URL rewrites caused the news pages to become .html as compared to all my other content pages which ends with a .php.

Instead of forcing the .html to .php or vice versa, I intend to remove both the .php and .html extension from the URL. However it can't work despite me putting a few different htaccess that other people had shown in the Internet.

Now, I am really a complete newbie at htaccess because I only have a very limited knowledge about it.

This is the .htaccess that CuteNews generates once I activate the URL rewrite functions,

```
# --- CUTENEWS[ST]
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms/show_news.php?cn_rewrite_url=$1 [L]
# --- CUTENEWS[ED]
```

Can anyone guide me along or something on removing the .html generated by this .htaccess as well as to remove the .php from my other content pages? Thanks.

Comment: `.htaccess` `RewriteRule`s don't remove the extensions from your code at all. They just make it so extension-less URLs work too. Your code needs to handle the extensions.

Comment: Forgotten to add this but I would love the URL to end with a trailing slash after the extension is remove.

Comment: This tool is very helpful: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: @smdrager yes, but doesn't support the use of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` yet

Answer (score 1):

To remove the .php or .html extension  add the 2 last lines of this .htaccess extract in your htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```